# Error migrating from sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

I am currently using workbench 6.0 to migrate MS SQL server 2000 to MySQL 5.6.
I keep getting an error saying;

```
    invalid timestamp literal detected
```

I did a bit of reserch and found out that it was because of conflicting datatypes. MYSQL datetime does not contain milliseconds but the SQL Server datetime datatype contains milliseconds.

It was suggested that I convert the datetime type to a smalldatetime in SQL Server provided I didn't mind losing the milliseconds.

I did that to all applicable tables, how ever I still get that darn error message in the log when migrating.

SQL server didn't get rid of the milliseconds after changing the data type and MySQL is clearly importing them that same way.

Any clue as to what I should be doing? Or any work around to this?

Comment: Since 5.6.4, MySQL supports up to microseconds (and prior to that, they would just be discarded). And even with strict SQL modes I'd expect a different error: `1292 Incorrect datetime value`. So it looks to me as a Workbench issue.

Comment: `Timestamp` column in SQL Server is not a `DATETIME` type, now it is reffered to as `rowversion` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx. VS MySQL where `TIMESTAMP` is in fact a datetime data type.

Comment: So in other words, I should just consider it a workbench error and ignore it? 'Cause doing a side by side comparison, the data still looks the same.